# How to customize action when matching item exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am checking whether a book exists, and if so, render some action. I'd like this action to be a popup message or redirecting to another page.

Here's the code in my model:

```rb
def
    existing_book = Book.find_by('author LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?', "#{self.author}", "#{self.name}")

    if existing_book != nil
      errors.add(:name, message: "This book may already exist.")
    end
end
```

The problem is that besides `errors.add` to show the error text on the same screen, I can't get it to do popup message or redirect. `redirect_to` or such code that work in controller doesn't work in this model file. How can I do a popup message or redirect in this case?

If that is impossible, how can I at least make the error message show more than one model? Above, there's only `:name`, but I'd like to show both name and author. Right now the error message shows as: "Name This book may already exist."

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Could you show **ALL** of the relevant code, so we can see what's going on? Redirecting is the job of a *controller*, not a model. The code you've shown above is presumably a *model validation*, which implies you're trying to create/update a record via a controller action? It's hard to see what exactly you're trying to do, because you've barely shown us half of the code.

Comment: I mean, the title of your question is "How to customize action?..." and you haven't shown us any of your controller action! Without more context, all I will say is: **with an `if` statement**.